# MS SQL Server Can Not Get A Select Sum Column Correct

Tags: sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio. What I am trying to do is get a sum as one of my columns for each record but that sum would only sum up values based on the values from the first two columns.

The query looks like this so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
BeginPeriod,
EndPeriod,
(

    SUM((select FO_NumPages from tbl_Folder where FO_StatisticDateTime > BeginPeriod AND FO_StatisticDateTime < EndPeriod))

) AS PageCount

FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,tbl_Folder.FO_StatisticDateTime),0),101) AS BeginPeriod,
        tbl_Folder.FO_PK_ID AS COL1ID
    FROM
        tbl_Folder
)AS ProcMonth1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,tbl_Folder.FO_StatisticDateTime)+1,0),101) AS EndPeriod,
        tbl_Folder.FO_PK_ID AS COL2ID
    FROM
        tbl_Folder      
)AS ProcNextMonth1
ON ProcMonth1.COL1ID = ProcNextMonth1.COL2ID
ORDER BY BeginPeriod DESC;
```

The table I am getting the data from would look something like this:

```
FO_StatisticsDateTime  | FO_PK_ID  | FO_NumPages
-------------------------------------------------

03/21/2013             |  24       | 5
04/02/2013             |  22       | 6
```

I want the sum to count the number of pages for each record that is between the beginning period and the end period for each record.

I understand the sum with the select statement has an aggregate error in that function for the column values. But is there a way I can get that sum for each record?

Comment: When you say the number of pages "for each record", what exactly are you calling a record?   With your sample data, what would be your desired results?

Comment: a record as in per row. so the result might look like:

beginperiod  | endperiod    | number of pages

02/01/2013   | 03/01/2013 | 34

for every row I Im looking for the sum of page numbers that occured between the values of the begin period and the end period.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trusting that everything in the FROM clause works as you expect, and would suggest that this change to the top part of your query should get what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
BeginPeriod,
EndPeriod,
(Select SUM(FO_NumPages) 
from tbl_Folder f1 
where f1.FO_StatisticDateTime >= ProcMonth1.BeginPeriod 
AND f1.FO_StatisticDateTime <= ProcNextMonth1.EndPeriod
) AS PageCount

FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,tbl_Folder.FO_StatisticDateTime),0),101) AS BeginPeriod,
        tbl_Folder.FO_PK_ID AS COL1ID
    FROM
        tbl_Folder
)AS ProcMonth1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,tbl_Folder.FO_StatisticDateTime)+1,0),101) AS EndPeriod,
        tbl_Folder.FO_PK_ID AS COL2ID
    FROM
        tbl_Folder      
)AS ProcNextMonth1
ON ProcMonth1.COL1ID = ProcNextMonth1.COL2ID
ORDER BY BeginPeriod DESC;
```

Comment: That totally did it! Thank you!! As good as Id like to think I am in SQL my skill are not that great so I could not get the right syntax. Thank you so so so much again! :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select BeginDate,
    EndDate,
    SUM(tbl_Folder.FO_NumPages) AS PageCount
from (select distinct dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,FO_StatisticDateTime),0) BeginDate from tbl_Folder) begindates
join (select distinct dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,FO_StatisticDateTime)+1,0) EndDate from tbl_Folder) enddates
on BeginDate < EndDate
join tbl_Folder
on tbl_Folder.FO_StatisticDateTime >= BeginDate
    and tbl_Folder.FO_StatisticDateTime < EndDate
group by BeginDate, EndDate
order by 1, 2
```

I changed your expressions that converted the dates, because the string comparisons won't work as expected.

It joins two sub-queries of distinct beginning and ending dates to get all the possible date combinations.  Then it joins that with your data that falls between the dates so that you can come up with your sum.

Comment: Thanks Brian! This helps me a lot also!